# Select nth-last-child when not every element has the selecting class-jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors

I'm looking for something like the following **CSS4** selector in `jQuery`:
`:nth-last-match(selector)`

I need to select the **second to last** element from a list of elements where not every element has a `class` - Please see the following example highlighting what i am hopeing to achieve.

```js
$('.select:nth-last-child(2)').addClass('selected');
```

```css
.test.selected { color:red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
<div class="test">a</div>
<div class="test select">a</div>
<div class="test">a</div>
<div class="test select">a</div>
<div class="test">a</div>
<div class="test">a</div>
<div class="test select">EXPECTED SELECTION</div> //This element should be selected
<div class="test">a</div>
<div class="test select">a</div>
<div class="test">a</div>
</div>
```

Many Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **[.get()](https://api.jquery.com/get/)** method with **negative argument** value:

```
var expected = $('div .select').get(-2);
$(expected).css('background', 'red');
```

So, `.get(-1)` is the last element of this collection, and `.get(-2)` is second from the end.

Check the **below snippet**

```js
var expected = $('div .select').get(-2);
$(expected).css('background', 'red');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div>
  <div class="test">a</div>
  <div class="test select">a</div>
  <div class="test">a</div>
  <div class="test select">a</div>
  <div class="test">a</div>
  <div class="test">a</div>
  <div class="test select">EXPECTED SELECTION</div>
  <div class="test">a</div>
  <div class="test select">a</div>
  <div class="test">a</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Nicely done; I'd completely forgotten about the `get()` method (or that it could use negative indices). :)

Comment: This answer is perfect, Thanks